# Springboot kotlin problem with mapping kotlin enum to Postgre enum type

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, enums

In Postgre database I defined new `ENUM` type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE role_type as ENUM ( 'DOCTOR', 'NURSE');
```

In Kotlion code, I have the following definition:

```kotlin
enum class Role ( val roleName: String) {
    Doctor("DOCTOR"),
    Nurse("NURSE");

    companion object {
        fun getFromName(roleName: String) =
            when(roleName) {
                "DOCTOR" -> Doctor
                else -> Nurse
            }
    }

}
```

and I defined an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
data class Employee(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Int = 0,
    @Column(name="first_name", length = 50)
    val firstName: String,
    @Column(name="last_name", length = 50)
    val lastName: String,
    @Column(name="is_admin")
    val isAdmin: Boolean,
    @Column(name="username")
    val username: String,
    @Column(name="role")
    var role: Role,
    @Column(name="password_hash", length = 128)
    val passwordHash: String,
)
```

Also, I defined an `AttributeConverter`:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
class RoleConverter: AttributeConverter<Role, String> {
    override fun convertToDatabaseColumn(role: Role): String = role.roleName
    override fun convertToEntityAttribute(roleName: String?): Role = Role.values().first { r -> r.roleName == roleName }
}
```

When I try to execute the folowing line:

```
employeeService.saveEmployee(
            Employee(firstName = "John", lastName = "Doe", isAdmin = true, passwordHash = "1234", username = "john", role = Role.Doctor)
        )
```

, I receive the following error:

```
Hibernate: insert into employees (first_name, is_admin, last_name, password_hash, role, username) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

ERROR:  column "role" is of type role_type but expression is of type character varying at character 112

HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

How can I solve this bug?

I also tried with setting `@Type` and `Enumerated` annotations, but with no luck:

```
@Type(type = "role_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
var role: Role,
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be OK, have you tried it without auto apply annotation on converter and with direct converter specification on attribute?

```
@Convert(converter = RoleConverter::class)
var role: Role,
```

Also, have you tried debugging, if the **convertToDatabaseColumn** method is called on save?

Comment: Yes, I tried, I get a log output. Also, `@Converter` has only `autoApply` member